# What is a "shot" in machine learning?

Tags: machine-learning

I keep on hearing this term "shot" used in machine learning.

**Is a "shot" well-defined?**

From what I can tell, "shot" is a synonym for "example". Most machine learning systems seem to be "multi-shot" meaning you have a huge dataset that has many different examples of different categories. However, for a system to have ["one-shot" capabilities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-shot_learning) means that it is able to predict the category of something given exactly one example. Similarly, ["few-shot" applications](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p1b5aiTrGzY) seem to only need a few examples in order to perform some function with the input. And ["zero-shot" learning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-shot_learning) seems to be making predictions without any examples during training.

**Is a shot just an example?**

Given the evidence above, it seems like this is the case, but it also seems like it's a little bit more nuanced, something like *a shot is a post-training example when 0 examples were given during training*. But I'm not sure if this is right, thus the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A shot is a single example available for machine learning. So "one-shot" means you're given just the one example for each class.

Answer (score 0):

I asked this question before starting my PhD in natural language processing, and I think I have a slightly better grasp of the term now.

When discussing prompting large language models (LLMs), **a *shot* refers to an example given in the prompt to the model**, rather than an example it was trained on. For example, 0-shot prompting is when you just ask an LLM a question; single-shot prompting is when you first show how one question should be answered and then ask a similar question and let the LLM answer it, all within one prompt.

I imagine that this terminology was borrowed from earlier training techniques, where, [as the previous answer mentions](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/90464/63455), shots were merely training examples. But I do think the language has changed to differentiate between the two when talking about LLMs. For LLMs, shots are specifically given within a single prompt, so a single example may have multiple shots within it.